# Confusing SET IDENTITY_INSERT Errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that inserts into a table which has a trigger that inserts into another table.

Both need to insert the IDS and not let SQL Server handle them with identity increment.

The scenario goes as follows :

1. The stored procedure is invoked

   ```
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT X ON

    INSERT INTO X (identity) 
    VALUES (IdentityValue)

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT X OFF
   ```
2. The trigger runs on insert

   ```
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Y ON

    INSERT INTO Y (identity) 
    VALUES (SAMEIdentityValue)

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Y OFF
   ```

Is there a way to handle this? Maybe like isolating the trigger context or any other solution

Comment: In general, I'd say if you're using identity_insert for anything other than "one-off" maintenance tasks, and here where you're wanting to use it *routinely*, something's gone seriously awry in designing the database. If you *care* about the actual values being assigned, identity was probably the wrong tool to use in the first place.

Comment: Why do the tables have IDENTITY then, if yiou don't want to use it?

Comment: cause it is used it in most cases , this is a new case that i am trying to handle